# How to select multiple file extentions in php

Tags: php, file

I want to select files with multiple extensions my files may have different formats such as `2.jpg or 3.png or 4.gif`
I wrote this code but I don't know how to select file extensions.
as you see in this line :

```
$avatar = "/path/photo-" .$uid. ".png or jpg or gif";
```

How I can select different extensions

```
<?php 

$uid = "1";
$avatar = "/path/photo-" .$uid. ".png or jpg or gif";

 if(!file_exists($avatar))
   {

   $noavatar_img = "http://www.myforum.com/default_thumb.png";
    header( 'Location: '.$noavatar_img.'' ) ;
}else{
    $avatar_img = "http://www.myforum.com/photo-" . $uid . ".png or jpg or gif";
    header( 'Location: '.$avatar_img.'' ) ;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: For the extensions you want to accept you could have an array. You can then loop through said array and append each extension to the filename, checking it exists each time.

Comment: what is the logic of this? I do not understand. create an array with the 3 extensions, check if any of that is exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$uid = "1";
$extensions = array('.png', '.jpg', '.gif');
foreach($extensions as $extension)
{
  $avatar = "/path/photo-" . $uid . $extension;
  if(file_exists($avatar)){
    $avatar_img = "http://www.myforum.com/photo-" . $avatar
    header( 'Location: '.$avatar_img.'' ) ;
  }
}

$noavatar_img = "http://www.myforum.com/default_thumb.png";
header( 'Location: '.$noavatar_img.'' ) ;
```

Comment: This wont work. It will redirect on the 1st iteration. Also your redirect are back to front

Comment: It still wont work. If the file is a jpg or gif, it will never get used because the 1st iteration of the loop will check for a png, not find it and redirect to default, before the other extensions are even checked

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of allowed extensions, iterate the array and check if the file exists.
If so redirect to it. If not redirect to default:

```
<?php 
$uid = "1";
$extensions = ['.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif'];
foreach($extensions as $ext){

    if(file_exists("/path/photo-" .$uid. $ext){
        $avatar_img = "http://www.myforum.com/photo-" . $uid . $ext;
        header( 'Location: '.$avatar_img);
        die(); //end script execution 
    }
}
$noavatar_img = "http://www.myforum.com/default_thumb.png";
header( 'Location: '.$noavatar_img) ;
```